# EPSG:4326 being saved as CRS:84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I am trying to save a GeoJSON file in QGIS as EPSG:4326, but it keeps being saved as CRS84.

EPSG:4326 and CRS84 are the same except CRS84 saves coordinates as long, lat - and EPSG:4326 saves them as lat, long.

When I open the saved file in QGIS it's read as EPSG:4326, but really the file is CRS84. I know this because when I open the GeoJSON file in notepad it's listed as CRS84, and when I load the file in Shapely it's recognized as CRS84.

What's going on here?

I've tried this on both QGIS 3.6.3 and QGIS 3.4.8 with the same result.

Comment: What is your problem? GeoJSON is WGS84 longitude-latitude by definition https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946, and also in the original version of the specification coordinate order was always longitude-latitude or easting-northing independently on coordinate reference system. It may be wrong that CRS:84 and EPSG:4326 are used as synonyms, but if you don't pay attention to that everything just works.